# Migration of MS CRM 4 to CRM 2013 in hosting environement

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I have to migrate CRM 4 to CRM 2013 in hosting environment.CRM 4 is deployed in hosting environment.I got the database from hosting company to test migration.What are the steps I should take for this migration.I am a newbie in CRM environment, did few developments on CRM 4 using their SDKs, and reporting stuff.

1. Do I need to ask some other thing from hosting company besides database.
2. What steps should I take to handle login users accounts(specially if they are in Active-Directory of hosting company) can I deploy that database directly with out it? (I tried to attach that database directly with crm4 deployment but it was of no avail, unable to access login page after bindnig that live database of crm4 with my on-premises deployment)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to upgrade a CRM 4.0 database directly to CRM 2013. You'll need to first upgrade it to CRM 2011, and then upgrade it to CRM 2013.

During the import, you'll be asked to map users from the imported database to users in your local Active Directory.

So the steps are:

1. Install CRM 2011 locally.
2. Make sure all users are in your local AD.
3. Import CRM 4.0 database.
4. Map users.
5. Upgrade local CRM 2011 to CRM 2013 (users will already be mapped).

Hope that helps!

Comment: so far I found following migration technology updgrades needs to be done.
1)CRM SDK is changed.
2)javascript model is changed.
3)Plugins are no longer supported.
4)Replacing sql with fetchXML in reporting(for crm online).

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Plugins are absolutely still supported and quite backwards compatible! Otherwise I can't think of anything else.